# Overlay view cannot be removed from map

Tags: ios, overlay, mkoverlay

I have created some overlays:

```
  //additionally draw an overlay
    MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:choosenCountry.coordinate radius:choosenCountry.placeMark.region.radius/4];
    circle.title = @"test";
    [_mapView addOverlay:circle];
```

and:

```
 -(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id)overlay 
{MKCircleView* circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
circleView.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
circleView.lineWidth = 2;

return circleView;}
```

But now, somehow I need to remove them but I can't:

```
- (void)clearOverlays{
NSArray *overlayCountries = [self.mapView overlays];
[self.mapView removeOverlays:overlayCountries];  
}
```

Do you know, how this can be done? Thanks!

Comment: For the addOverlay, you are using _mapView but in clearOverlays, you are using self.mapView.  Why is that and are you sure they are referencing the same map view?

Comment: It is the same thing actually. Anyway, I changed in clearOverlays to _mapView, it is not working. Do you have some other hints? Thanks!

Comment: Then that code should work.  Something else is wrong.  In clearOverlays, put this NSLog at the top of the method and see what it says: `NSLog(@"mapView = %@, ov=%@", mapView, mapView.overlays);`.

Comment: The codes described above was totally working. The overlays added again after the deletion was due to a mistake(that the overlays are added again).